# RSpec how to test an argument data type passed to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

I need to test the passed argument type is an integer. Here is my test spec:

```
require 'ball_spin'

RSpec.describe BallSpin do
  describe '#create_ball_spin' do
    subject(:ball_spin) { BallSpin.new }
    it 'should accept an integer argument' do
      expect(ball_spin).to receive(:create_ball_spin).with(an_instance_of(Integer))
      ball_spin.create_ball_spin(5)
    end
  end
end
```

My code:

```
class BallSpin
  def create_ball_spin n
    "Created a ball spin #{n} times" if n.is_a? Integer
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Apologize for using old RSpec syntax, below I updated my code to use the latest one:

```
it 'should accept an integer argument' do
  expect(ball_spin).to receive(:create_ball_spin).with(an_instance_of(Integer))
  ball_spin.create_ball_spin(5)
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You may add a block to `receive` to check the method params:

```
expect(ball_spin).to receive(:create_ball_spin) do |arg|
  expect(arg.size).to be_a Integer
end
```

You may find details in [`Arbitrary Handling` section](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#arbitrary-handling) of `rspec-mocks` documentation.

UPDATE: Also you may use the same approach with `should` syntax:

```
ball_spin.should_receive(:create_ball_spin) do |arg|
  arg.should be_a Integer
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I got an error NoMethodError: undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec

Comment: @Kris MP, what version of Rspec are you using?

Comment: Oddly, my tests within the `arg` block are ignored fail|success. But if I set the values to a `@@class_variable` and called them outside, I could get rspec to respond to them.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that 5 is an instance of Fixnum and not Integer:

```
2.2.1 :005 > 5.instance_of?(Fixnum)
  => true 
2.2.1 :006 > 5.instance_of?(Integer)
  => false
```

UPDATE:
Ok, I've tried your code and the problem is Integer instead of Fixnum. Here is the correct assertion:

```
RSpec.describe BallSpin do
  describe '#create_ball_spin' do
    subject(:ball_spin) { BallSpin.new }
    it 'should accept an integer argument' do
      expect(ball_spin).to receive(:create_ball_spin).with(an_instance_of(Fixnum))
      ball_spin.create_ball_spin(5)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The use case of the `receive` matcher is to spec that a method *is called by someone*. But it is worth noting that the matcher itself doesn't call that method nor it tests if the method exists or if the list of possible arguments matches a given pattern.

It seems like your code doesn't call that method at all. A simple test that should pass might look like this:

```
subject(:ball_spin) { BallSpin.new }

it 'is called with an integer argument' do
  ball_spin.should_receive(:create_ball_spin).with(an_instance_of(Integer))
  ball_spin.create_ball_spin(5) # method called
end

it 'is not called' do
  ball_spin.should_not_receive(:create_ball_spin)
  # method not called
end
```

See section [Argument Matcher](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-5/docs/message-expectations).

Btw you use the old RSpec syntax and might want to consider updating your test suite to the new `expect` syntax.

Comment: @KrisMP I updated my answer. Because it feels to me like you expect the matcher work in a way it wasn't designed to work.

Comment: I have updated my question and adjust to RSpec new syntax